# Should I use sleep() function in C for long durations?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cron, sleep

I have a simple C program that will be running on my raspberry Pi. I am planning on taking data from sensors with an interval of 10-15 mins. Should I sleep()
the C program for this period in a loop then have it take the readings so on. Or should I not have a loop at all and have a command in cron tab to run the C program after every 15 mins or so. What are the advantages/disadvantages of sleep() in this case or is there a better approach this ?

Comment: Either way will work. If you run it continuously with sleep, you need to arrange for it to be restarted if it exits, but you can do that with `init` or `systemd`.

Comment: Put the code that checks the sensor into a thread or separate process, so your main proc can do other things (perhaps acknowledging that it is still alive). Have the sub-proc alert the parent that something has changed, then do something.

Comment: so what if i do not have anything else going on in main proc, this is the only thing I am doing getting data from sensor once after 15 mins. would i still want to create another thread for what? @stevieb

Comment: The main proc could stay dormant but alive, perhaps to listen for an external call for 'check in' or whatever. If it is sleeping, you can never tell what's going on with it. At minimum, the main thread/proc can be logging every X seconds/minutes, so if you can't look at it directly, you can at least ensure its log file is being updated appropriately. (log file, DB table etc)

Comment: ok so this makes more sense than just using sleep but would you still say that having the program run at all times on the pi is a better approach than to using a cron job for the task after the intervals? @stevieb

Comment: That depends on the load of starting the process every X minutes from `cron`. That's something that you need to benchmark/test in your specific environment. Personally, if your larger procs are already running, having one in the background that is small and just kicks them off is negligible compared to starting up a whole process every once in a while. Besides... you're already running the background procs, why not leave the boss dormant so it can be monitored?

Comment: In other words, a sleeping process can't respond. An aware process that is cycling, paying attention to its children can do things, again, like logging, listening etc. How will you ever be able to re-awaken a sleeping proc if it's in a `sleep(3600);`? It's dead as far as reaching it :) This is all imho by the way. I am not an expert. I'm just stating my experiences while dealing with other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Is data available in same machine where C program is running?

If not same, better to

1) have a small C collect data from sensor 
2) have a cron task that runs every 15 min, and that invokes your C program 
3) This way if network connection breaks between your C program and sensor where data available will not be a problem.

Also this approach helps you if any memory leak is there, also that would not be a problem.

Comment: If there are memory leaks, that should be a show-stopper. Throwing something toward the wind because it is transient is no excuse for allowing a leak or other bug.

Comment: No doubt it need to be fixed. A small C program does its work and exits will clear the memory leak caused by it as well.

Comment: A small C program that *doesn't* exit appropriately that has a memory leak is a big problem. Why just allow a program with a memory leak run, just because you think it won't run long? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: You can experiment it. Any C program running for short duration, even if it has memory leak, is not an issue at all for me. As process exits, the leaked memory is again back. However I will be for fixing the leaks. Point is small C program, short duration execution, its ok even if it has memory leak.

Comment: I'll avoid your code ;) Anyone who blindly allows memory leaks as common practice because they *think* the code won't run for long has their priorities incorrect. You've never seen a thread or a proc run longer than you have expected it to.

Comment: I develop lots of commercial applications in C, which runs for months together. For that kind of application, I would not keep any leaks, invalid access etc. Still I repeat, for small C program, short duration execution, I will not care much if memory leak is there or not.

Comment: I'm downvoting. Anyone who claims that a leak is ok as long as the proc doesn't run long enough, is giving very bad advice.

Comment: Then it seems you'll test blindly, and rush to product. Personally, I can't trust someone with that behaviour, and I hope others don't either.

Comment: I do not have much experience in C but I dont understand why anyone would allow a memory leak. I was told always free up memory when no longer needed.

Comment: Lets not drag it. I told I am for to fix leaks, however even if it is there, because nature of this program it would not affect. I did not tell knowingly keep memory leak.

Comment: I agree with Kamal. A program is never _perfect_. We choose to go near the perfection, always leaving something behind. That something can be (often) documentation, or nice user interface, or whatever, even memory leaks if they are not a problem (or there are bigger problems than that).